# JavaScript: extract all occurrences of a regular expression in a string

Tags: javascript, python, regex, string

I've got a Python function that makes a list of integer numbers out of a string containing clusters of digits:

```
def str_strip_numbers(s):
    """
    Returns a vector of integer numbers
    embedded in a string argument
    """
    return [int(x) for x in re.compile('\d+').findall(s)]
```

Given, say, `an1kb12s336z`, it returns `[1,12,336]`

What is the best way to get the same in JavaScript? I fiddled a bit with regular expressions, but did not gain much. This is not quite what I hoped for:

```
> var nn = /\d+/g
undefined
> nn
/\d+/g
> 'aba12gg4a'.search(nn)
3
```

Looks like I got the count of digits.

Comment: Couldn't you just split on anything that isn't a number, something like `"an1kb12s336z".split(/\D+/)`

Comment: You can use [this code demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8bjo2qx0/).

Comment: Did you Googled the title of the post you proposed ? You will find a lot of answers just by doing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Search is not the function you are looking for. String.prototype.search() returns the *position* of the first matching result.

You should instead use String.prototype.match: `'aba12gg4a'.match(/\d+/g)`. This will return an array of all matches found in the source string.

Comment: This won't return an array of numbers, but an array of strings.

Comment: I interpreted the substance of his question to be that the value he was getting back was not the set of matches he was expecting, rather than that the object was of the wrong type. If he wants them as numbers, he can always `matches.map(function(val) { return parseInt(val) })`, which is pretty much the direct equivalent of what he did in his original python code anyway.

Comment: Thank you very much, ''mwobey''!

Answer (score 1):

```
strStripNumbers: function(str) {
  return str.match(/\d+/g).map(__.parseInt);
}
```

__ means `lodash` library

Comment: well done Correct Answer.
if you are a JavaScript user like me you can do this way also
`const re = RegExp(/\d+/g)`

Answer (score 0):

you could try this. It will remove any letters from the string, and split to an array on the numbers. then filter out any values that don't parse with parseInt, meaning characters.

```
 'aba12gg4a'.split(/[^0-9]+/).reduce(function( ret, elem ){
        if (! isNaN(elem = parseInt(elem))){
            ret.push( elem );
        }
        return ret;
    }, []);
```

Comment: This returns a string array.

Comment: Use my code from the comment. Matching is better than splitting and is closer to what OP has in Python.